# How to connect to Bluetooth headset on Debian 8.1

Tags: debian, audio, bluetooth

I have a Bluetooth headset `Suicen AX610`. My system is Debian 8.1.

I want to run my headset, but I can't.

Debian 8.1 can find the headset,

[image]

But, Debian 8.1 can't pair the headset,

[image]

I try to set `Connection` for `on`, but it does not work.

I haven't installed any package. Because I looked many websites and each one says to set up the Bluetooth in a different way.

For instance, install a single package

$ sudo apt-get install bluez-tools

or install a lot of packages

$ sudo apt-get install bluez-audio pavucontrol bluez-firmware bluez-tools

or ...

$ sudo apt-get install bluez-utils bluez-gnome bluez-alsa

Can anyone help me with this issue?

My bluetooth folder:

```
$ ls /etc/bluetooth/
input.conf  main.conf  network.conf  proximity.conf
```

=========================================================================

I solved this problem, but my solution isn't good and I can't explain my solution. I used `trial and error` method.

1. Install a lot of packeges

   $ sudo apt-get install gnome-bluetooth pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth pavucontrol blueman bluetooth bluez
2. Edit /etc/default/bluetooth to enable the following

   HID2HCI_ENABLED=1
   HID2HCI_UNDO=1
3. Get ???

   $ hcitool con

   Connections:
   < ACL 00:11:67:00:52:55 handle 2 state 1 lm MASTER AUTH ENCRYPT
4. Create .asoundrc

   $ sudo pico ~/.asoundrc

   pcm.bluetooth {
   type bluetooth
   device "00:11:67:00:52:55"
   profile "auto"
   }

   pcm.pulse {
   type pulse
   }

   ctl.pulse {
   type pulse
   }

   pcm.!default {
   type pulse
   }

   ctl.!default {
   type pulse
   }
5. Reboot the system
6. pairing by system tray
7. $ sudo killall pulseaudio
8. pairing again

Comment: Take a look what I did on [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/305111/cant-connect-to-bluetooth-devices-i-e-speakers-on-debian-jessie/305112#305112).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might just need to delete the pairing, then in terminal enter `sudo pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover` then pair with the headset

Answer (score 2):

`sudo service bluetooth restart`

This restores my headset as an output device in gnome sound settings, as it sometimes disappears.  The headset syncs/pairs/connects, but does not appear in the control panel (or alsamixer) and so I cannot switch audio devices.

Answer (score 1):

With `blueman-applet` I did it for a bluetooth speaker like this without restarting pulseaudio:

- Run `blueman-applet`
- Pair my bluetooth speaker
- Right click it in `blueman-applet` window
- Choose "Connect -> Audio Sink"
- In `pavucontrol` in "Configuration" tab, switched my sound card from "Analog Stereo Duplex" to "Off" and chose "High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink) for my speaker.